# Should I have a different driver for my 32" ledtv 720P

Tags: drivers, display

Can someone tell me if I should have a different driver and which one set as the monitor driver for a 32" 720p led tv, I can't find any help on this as to if it should be chnged from the one XP has in there, do I need to change or not and if so any driver recommendations to which one I could be using in stead. Thanks Joseph

Comment: Your only driver needs are to keep the one for your video card up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Display drivers are specific to your **display adapter**, not the actual screen/destination. Your manufacturer already installed the drivers your computer needs, so you shouldn't need to install another driver.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to display drivers you should be worrying more about the graphics adapter in your computer than the monitor itself. The graphics adapter is the part that varies enough to need different drivers, displays are essentially all the same (high end displays often come with a CD, but usually all you'll find on it is color profiles and the manual).

You should check out what graphics adapter your machine has installed. One way to do this is to open the Device Manager (in the control panel) and see what it lists under Display Adapters. You may find that it gives you a manufacturer and model number for a graphics adapter, probably from a company like Intel, nVidia, or ATI/AMD.